# JPA and Hibernate: Entity with composite primary key using multiple @Id

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm using SpringBoot with JPA and Hibernate.

For a specific entity I need to use a primary key composed by a relationship + a field.

Something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "book",
    uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"book_id", 
    "field_a"}))
public class Book extends MyBaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book")
    private List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
@IdClass(CustomID.class)
public class Author extends MyBaseEntity {
    
    /* Here the composite key */
    @Id
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
    private Book book;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "field_a", nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID fieldA;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private Instant creationDate;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "last_mod_date")
    private Instant lastModificationDate;

}

public class CustomID implements Serializable {
    private UUID book;
    private UUID fieldA;
}
```

Using this approach, after some inserts on the DB, for Author entity book_id column contains values like these:

`ÃFË5ÊL©T¾Äd`
Why? Why there aren't Book primary keys values?

Comment: You don't need the foreign key `book` in your composite key. Remove it.

Comment: @K.Nicholas do you mean that I need to remove book from CustomID class? In this case, do I need to keep '@Id' for both fields into my entity?

Comment: @K.Nicholas I missed one aspect, I need to have also a constraint: I need to have book_id and field_a unique (composite key). I updated my question. Using your solution this constraint seams not works. Saving an Author with the same book and field_a the save will not raise any constraint exception and the creation date will be NULL

Comment: Really, you don't need a composite key at all. Just and `@Id` for Authors with a `@ManyToOne` for `Authors`. You should keep in mind that Books and Authors is typically a `ManyToMany` relationship, but first things first.

Comment: This is just an example, into my real scenario I need @ManyToOne. 
And into Authors the required constraint is that I can't to have the same author for the same book.

Comment: Probably a typo, but the field `UUID book` in `CustomID` should be `Book book`